# SOMETHING WRONG IN DHT22 PROGRAM showing error as expected unqualified id before'. ' token

Tags: arduino-uno, compilation-errors

I am using a arduino and dht22 sensor for my project purpose annd gettting error as expecte before unqualified '.' token

MY CODE IS :

```
#include <DHT.h>


#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Wire.h>


#define DHTPIN 8     
#define DHTTYPE DHT22   

LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2);

int ldrpin=A0;
int ldr=0;


DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);


//
//
//
//
//
//
//
//


void setup() 
    {

   lcd.begin(16, 2);
   Serial.begin (9600);
   DHT .begin();
     pinMode(ldrpin,INPUT);

}

//
//
//
//
//
//
//

void loop() 
    {

  lcd.setCursor(0,0);


 //ldr 
  ldr=analogRead(ldrpin);



//LDR DISPLAY
  Serial.println("LIGHT INTENSITY");
  Serial.println(ldr);
  Serial.print(" lx\t");
  delay(2000);

   lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0); 

   lcd.print("LIGHT INTENSITY");
    delay(200);
    lcd.print(ldr);
      delay(2000);


//dht22 
delay(2000);

   int chk = DHT.read(DHTPIN);
    float humidity = DHT.humidity;
    float temperature = DHT.temperature;



//dht22 display
1.  Serial.println("Humidity: "); 
2.    Serial.print(h);
3.    Serial.print(" %\t");
4.    Serial.println("Temperature: "); 
5.    Serial.print(t);
  Serial.println(" *C ");
```

my error message is

```
Arduino: 1.6.4 (Windows 8.1), Board: "Arduino Uno"

LCD.ino: In function 'void setup()':
LCD:38: error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token
LCD.ino: In function 'void loop()':
LCD:80: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
LCD:81: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
LCD:82: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
LCD:87: error: expected ';' before 'Serial'
LCD:88: error: expected ';' before 'Serial'
LCD:89: error: expected ';' before 'Serial'
LCD:90: error: expected ';' before 'Serial'
LCD:91: error: expected ';' before 'Serial'
expected unqualified-id before '.' token
```

This report would have more information with
  "Show verbose output during compilation"
  enabled in File > Preferences.

some one help me please!!

Comment: Don’t shout. No need for an ALLCAPS title

Answer (score 1):

Line 38, 80, 81, 82: `DHT` is a class name, `dht` is an instance of that class (an object, a variable), so write:

```
   dht.begin();
```

And all those call to DHT.something? Wrong too. Reemplaza DHT with dht.

All others errors: Why are you written "1. ", "2. ", before statements? Delete those numbers:

```
Serial.println("Humidity: "); 
Serial.print(h);
Serial.print(" %\t");
Serial.println("Temperature: "); 
Serial.print(t);
Serial.println(" *C ");
```

Also, you are missing a "}" to end loop().

When you correct this errors, others will surface.